# Legend position set in theme is saving as "right" even when set to another value

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend

I'm creating a bunch of graphs that I want to share a theme, for consistency because who doesnt love consistency.

All of my `theme()` elements are holding except for `legend.position`, and I'm all out of ideas.

The gist is as follows:

I want a theme that I can add to all of my graphs to give them the same formatting. There are two graphs that I'm creating, so I'm creating two similar themes.

I'm also splitting up my graphs in a possibly? nontraditional way. E.g. creating a graph template that includes the basic ggplot layers, but leaves out geom_point or geom_line, so that I can reuse those templates. Currently, I'm adding the theme that I've created in there.

Here's an example of one theme. The last parameter I set is for the legend to appear at the bottom.

```
mytheme <- theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"),
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1, size = 9),
                 axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9), 
                 legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Lets test it out!

```
plot_template <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  facet_grid(~cyl) +
  mytheme

testplot <- plot_template +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = drat)) +
  scale_color_continuous()
testplot
```

... and the legend appears on the right.

When I look at `mytheme` in the environment, it shows as a list of 65, and upon opening I see `legend.position`. It is listed as a type of `charater[1]` with a value of `'right'`. This doesnt seem right, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Everything works just fine if I add `legend.position` separately, but this defeats the entire purpose of creating the unifying theme so I dont have to add each element to every graph.

```
mytheme <- theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"),
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1, size = 9),
                 axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9)) + 
  theme_bw()

plot_template <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  facet_grid(~cyl) + 
  mytheme +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

testplot <- plot_template +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = drat)) +
  scale_color_continuous()
```

Has anyone encountered this before or can see something that I'm doing wrong?

My guess is that I'm not fully understanding how setting a theme `mytheme <- ...` works, and I'm using it inappropriately, but nothing in the documentation is leading me to believe that I'm doing something funky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mytheme <- theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"),
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1, size = 9),
                 axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9), 
                 legend.position = "bottom")
```

By placing theme_bw() after your custom theme specifications you overwrite them

Comment: by-golly-gee, you did it! Do you know why theme_bw() overrides the legend position but not any of the other elements set in the theme()?